# expected primary-expression before '<<' token

Tags: c++

can anyone explain this error i dont understand why im getting it.

```
310:32: error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token
```

in this line of code.

> cout << "Name: " << setw(22) << profile[x].name << endl;

Comment: Try splitting into more than one `cout` statement.  This will help clarify which item is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the following to the beginning of your file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
```